# Are there other ways to access columns in a CSV similar to "&:first"?

Tags: ruby, csv

I need to modify some values in some columns of a CSV and after modifying them I need to copy them to a new CSV. For the first column, I do this:

```
my_csv = CSV.open('MyCSV.csv')
first_column = my_csv.map(&:first)
#do something with them
```

So, how do I access the other columns since there is no `&:second` or `&:third`?

Comment: you could use the names of the columns like 'csv['name']' will be easier.

Answer (score 2):

you could also try this:

## test1.csv

```
name,surname,age
em,good,23
cat,cute,40
```

## ruby.rb

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.read('test1.csv', headers: true)
p csv['age'] 

#=> ["23", "40"]
```

Comment: Thanks. But what is `p` here?

Comment: So, `p` is the same as `puts`?